# Scrape table from html

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv

How to scrape the table from this html with pandas and bs4 then get the first table as the main column and second table and convert it into an csv with python?

```
<table background-color="#00CED1" border="1">
<tr><th>STT</th><th>Há» vÃ  tÃªn</th><th>Sá» bÃ¡o danh</th><th>ChuyÃªn</th>&gt;<th>Äm ToÃ¡n chung</th><th>Äm 
VÄn chung</th><th>Äm ChuyÃªn</th><th>Tá»ng Äiá»m</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>ThÃ¡i BÃ¡ Viá»t An</td><td>CO.0001</td><td>ToÃ¡n</td><td>8.75</td><td>4.75</td><td>7.5</td><td>28.5</t
d></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did I get this right? You want to:

- convert the html table to csv
- the first row (table header) should become the first column in the csv
- the second row (data) should become the second column in the csv

If yes, try this:

```py
import csv

import pandas as pd

html = """
<table background-color="#00CED1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>STT</th>
        <th>Há» vÃ  tÃªn</th>
        <th>Sá» bÃ¡o danh</th>
        <th>ChuyÃªn</th>
        &gt;
        <th>Äm ToÃ¡n chung</th>
        <th>Äm VÄn chung</th>
        <th>Äm ChuyÃªn</th>
        <th>Tá»ng Äiá»m</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>ThÃ¡i BÃ¡ Viá»t An</td>
        <td>CO.0001</td>
        <td>ToÃ¡n</td>
        <td>8.75</td>
        <td>4.75</td>
        <td>7.5</td>
        <td>28.5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""

table = pd.read_html(html)[0]

with open('somefile.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, dialect='excel')
    for name in table:
        writer.writerow([name, table.iloc[0][name]])
```